# JQuery-Submit Form with Var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hello I have a var in a function when I hit submit...I want to pass the var"fieldNames" to my form....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#sortable").each(function() {

        var fieldNames = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();


    });
    $("#detColumnSortorder").submit;
});
```

});

I want to pass this in my form:  fieldNames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put in a hidden input field in your form. Then set the value on the hidden field. That way when the form submits, the value in the hidden field will be submitted.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fieldNames" value="" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#sortable").each(function() {    
        var fieldNames = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
        $('input[name=fieldNames]').val(fieldNames);
    });
    $("#detColumnSortorder").submit;
});
```